# CSS color marked as invalid by code inspector

Tags: css

On [this page](http://secretcitywalks.co/london/london-1-london-eye-tate-modern/), there is a "read more..." link towards the end of the page, enclosed in `<span id="s-hpi"></span>`

There is CSS:

```
#s-hpi {
  color: 0000FF;
  cursor: hand;
}
```

but Chrome code inspector says both these rules are invalid.

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW color codes without the `#` and `cursor:hand` worked on _old_ versions of IE (emphasis on the "old").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mention above You're missing the **#** before the hex color. for cursor you can use **pointer**

```
#s-hpi {
color: #0000FF;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Or shorter `#00F`

Comment: Silly me.  Thanks.  On stackoverflow my question would have received 3-4 downvotes because I didn't know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `#` before the hex color:

```
color: 0000FF;
```

should be:

```
color: #0000FF;
```